# Clock-Solitare Game/Aggregation

Tags: java, oop, aggregation, bluej

I'm trying to create a Clock Solitaire game for a mini project for fun with guidelines from a buddies programming class. I have my deck and card classes running. However, I am supposed to implement a pile class. I'm not sure how familiar people are with clock solitaire as this is the first time I have heard of it...  In Clock Solitaire, there are thirteen piles of cards. (In the instructions it is an Array of Piles in a circle, filled with four face-down cards and a pile in the middle of the circle). At the beginning of the game, the cards will all be face down. There is a pile in the middle of the circle that is considered the "Kings pile". You have to "remove" the top card from the kings' pile and place it "Face Up" at the bottom of the correct pile.

In my Pile class I am required to have 2 void methods:

```
---addCardFaceUp() and addCardFaceDown().
```

As well as a method:

```
---public Card removeCard()
```

Which returns a Card object...

My question is kind of long and runs together. Sorry in advance... 
I'm having trouble getting inspiration as to how to I could fill my Array of Piles with "Face down" cards at the beginning of the game. I haven't tried anything because I'm having some writers block with it. Has anyone done a similar project and can provide some direction? Or a way to just label the cards as "Faceup or down..."

Comment: In order to "Remove and return the top card on the array" could i just do something like   return deck[0]; which would just be returning the card at the first index? Keep in mind Im attempting this with just the standard array. Not list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at the **data** that the pile class needs to keep. The Pile class will have to have a number of *class variables* in order to hold the data for each pile. Specifically, I can see that it would be useful to keep a count of the cards in the pile and a collection or list of cards. We also need a way to tell if each member of the collection is face-up, or face-down. We could achieve this by keeping a second collection or list, but rather than have it full of cards, have it full of Boolean values. Then, we could say that a card is face-up if the bool value at the same spot in the accompanying collection is *true* and face-down if it is *false*. Thus, we could store the data of cards in the pile, and face-up or face-down values.

The other part of a basic class would be the methods it employs. You must have a way to add (in both orientations) and remove cards from a pile, as your original post says. In order to do this more easily, you will need to use a more advanced data type than the simple array. Have a look at the [List class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for example, and make sure to put [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) to good use. Your add and remove methods will simply modify the collections or lists used to store your cards, and face-up/face-down Boolean values. In addition, you might have a value which simply turns a card in a particular spot in the list to the opposite orientation.

If you get stuck on something, it's likely a good opportunity to learn more about making your own Java classes. There are plenty of tutorials out there to help you along past this design stage, and into implementation. Happy coding!